# Open other file in the same package

Tags: ide, netbeans-8

I've recently started using Netbeans for a java project and there are some things that I relly miss from Eclipse.

The thing that annoys me most, causing a great deal of frustration and loss of focus, is file navigation.

A very common task is to open another file in the same directory/package as the file I am currently editing. In Eclipse I use the little "Link with Editor" button in the project explorer so that the explorer is always focused on the current file, hence allowing easy access to other files in the same folder.

In Netbeans I constantly scroll up and down the project list, opening and closing folders, looking for the right place.

Is there a simple way to synchronize the project explorer with the editor in Netbeans?

I want to be able to choose the file from a list, because in many cases I don't know the file name by heart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way for me is to use the `Select in Projects` feature, which takes the file explorer to the current file within the Project:

[image]

*PS: I don't know eclipse very well, so let me know if i'm on track or not*

Comment: I ended up using the "View->Synchronize editor with views" option listed in the answer to the duplicate question.